# maven compiler error with javac at release:prepare

Tags: java, maven, compiler-construction, release

i am having this issue. I saw many posts like this but i still can't solve this problem. This error appears when i put mvn release:prepare at the shell

```
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3:compile (default-compile) on project birthday-greeting-card-sender: Compilation failure
[INFO] [ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
[INFO] [ERROR] /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/../lib/tools.jar
[INFO] [ERROR] Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
[INFO] [ERROR] not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
[INFO] [ERROR] In most cases you can change the location of your Java
[INFO] [ERROR] installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
[INFO] [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[INFO] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[INFO] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I have set JDK at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 (Preferences-->Java-->Installed JRE). I also add this line into eclipse.ini, but it couldn't work either:

```
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

Does anybody have an idea about what is going on?

Comment: What is your $JAVA_HOME?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you also have this problem while running mvn in the shell, this is not related to eclipse, so setting:

```
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

won't have any effect.

This is also unrelated to the execution of goal `release:prepare` as the error occurs at compilation time. You can probably reproduce the same error by doing `mvn compile`.

Your JAVA_HOME is probably pointing to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64` (as seen in mvn log) while your jdk resides in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`.

To change JAVA_HOME and test the new setting, go in a shell and:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
mvn compile
```

If it works you can add `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` to your `~/.bashrc` file so that it gets set everytime.

Comment: But where i should change it? because i have changed from Preferences-->Java-->Installed JRE and it seems like it didn't do any effect

Comment: I fixed it! I downloaded jdk again and y set java_home and worked. Thanks!